# Codeigniter image manipulation output black

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-manipulation

I am getting a black area to handle this with CI, the image have 950x720

the first resize is ok
    $this->resize($data['upload_data']['full_path'], 220, 200, true, false);
but in the second, the error appear

code on gist:
https://gist.github.com/mateuspv/48ba464a557da9bbdf10

[image: ci black error]

```
<?php
/**
 * resize
 * @param  string $path   [description]
 * @param  int $width  [description]
 * @param  int $height [description]
 * @param  boolean $thumb  [description]
 * @param  boolean $ratio  [description]
 */
private function resize($path, $width, $height, $thumb, $ratio) {
        $config['image_library'] = 'GD2';
        $config['source_image'] = $path;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = $ratio;
        $config['create_thumb'] = $thumb;
        $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
        $config['width'] = $width;
        $config['height'] = $height;
        $this->image_lib->clear();
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();
        if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
            die($this->image_lib->display_errors());

        }
    }

//...

/**
 * TODO ~
 */
$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
$this->resize($data['upload_data']['full_path'], 220, 200, true, false);
$this->resize($data['upload_data']['full_path'], 450, 450, false, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think when you call function first time the script modify image itself and make it to 220px by 200px. and when you call function second time it take small image and resize it to 450px by 450px. this may be the error.. try to save first thumbnail to new destination file. try below code.

```
<?php
/**
 * resize
 * @param  string $path   [description]
 * @param  int $width  [description]
 * @param  int $height [description]
 * @param  boolean $thumb  [description]
 * @param  boolean $ratio  [description]
 */
private function resize($path, $width, $height, $thumb, $ratio) {
    $config['image_library'] = 'GD2';
    $config['source_image'] = $path;
    $config['new_image'] = PATH_TO_NEW_IMAGE;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = $ratio;
    $config['create_thumb'] = $thumb;
    $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
    $config['width'] = $width;
    $config['height'] = $height;
    $this->image_lib->clear();
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();
    if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
        die($this->image_lib->display_errors());

    }
}

//...

/**
 * TODO ~
 */
$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
$this->resize($data['upload_data']['full_path'], 220, 200, true, false);
$this->resize($data['upload_data']['full_path'], 450, 450, false, false);
```

Change PATH_TO_NEW_IMAGE to your destination file path. Hope this helps.

Comment: resize() is called twice here.. you can remove the first one, afaik.

Comment: @HerbertVan-Vliet resize() is called twice to create two images in different sizes.

Comment: I was thinking of the $this->image_lib->resize() in your resize function. The first one can go I think - as image_lib->resize() aready outputs the image bytes to the stream afaik.